# Cant pass arguments to OnClickListener?

Tags: android

I have my activity adapter that handles my main list of items.  When I click delete I would like to prompt user and if confirm delete the item from a list and refresh the view.

I have the logic that deletes the item but there doesn't seem to be a way to pass arguments down to the OnClickListener.  If I click a button on a list how do I capture the clicked position and how do I pass that to the OnClickListener function so that correct element can be deleted?

Any help would be appreciated,

Thank you,
Radek

```
 @Override
   public View getView(final int _position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    try {
        if(convertView == null){
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(com.mylist.www.R.layout.activity_main_row,parent,false);
        }

        TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(com.mylist.www.R.id.rowText);
        textView.setText(listItems.getJSONObject(_position).getString("description"));

        // set the checkbox stuff
        CheckBox chkEnabled = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(com.mylist.www.R.id.chkEnabled);

        textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try{
                    if (listItems != null){
                        JSONArray clickedItems = listItems.getJSONObject(_position).getJSONArray("listItems"); // position
                        Intent intent = new Intent(context, ListActivity.class);

                        intent.putExtra("listItems", clickedItems.toString());
                        context.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

        });

        Button btnNavigate = (Button) convertView.findViewById(com.mylist.www.R.id.btnDelete);
        btnNavigate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try{
                    if (listItems != null){

                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                        builder.setMessage("Are you sure?").setPositiveButton("Yes", dialogClickListener)
                                .setNegativeButton("No", dialogClickListener).show();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

        });


        return convertView;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        try {
            switch (which){
                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                    //Yes button clicked
                    listItems.remove(position); //????? how do I pass it

                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject();
                    jObj.put("Items", listItems);

                    editor.putString("json",jObj.toString());
                    editor.commit();

                    ((MainActivity)context).refreshView();

                    break;

                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                    //No button clicked
                    break;
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you store position in another variable and later on use it

```
int currentPosition;
```

store current view position in `getView()` when user clicks a button

```
currentPosition = position;

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
builder.setMessage("Are you sure?").setPositiveButton("Yes", dialogClickListener)
                            .setNegativeButton("No", dialogClickListener).show();
```

and then use it in your listener

```
listItems.remove(currentPosition);
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey u have one mistek there ?

```
listitem.remove(postion)
```

to replace

```
listitem.remove(_position);
```

Comment: The position is what I was not sure how to access. Your comments gave me an idea, I moved my dialogClickListener  inside getView as inner class, this way I could directly access the _position variable without having to pass it as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

declare currentItemPosition variable as global in the class

```
int currentItemPosition;
```

store position when user clicks on button like

```
currentItemPosition = _position;
```

and use it in your listener

```
listItems.remove(currentItemPosition);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set tag to each row while inflating:

```
view.setTag(position)
```

then on button click you can get the position of that row as

```
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //current row view clicked position
                int currentItemPosition = (Integer) button.getTag();

                 //now remove the item from the list at the clicked position
                 listItems.remove(currentItemPosition);

            }
        });
```

This way you can have the position of the item that user clicked from the listview and then do the further operations. Hope this helps you

Answer (score 1):

With this implementation, we can't get the position. If you want to get position please modify your code as below -

```
  AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                            builder.setMessage("Are you sure?").setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                    // you can get position here
                                }
                            }).setNegativeButton("No", dialogClickListener).show();
```

Comment: thank you got lots of good various approaches all worked great